# Before You Go VS Before Going

Tags: meaning-in-context, verb-forms

I have this English sentence from an English book:

> Don't forget to turn off the light before you go to bed!

I was wondering whether I can use the -ing form this way and get the same meaning:

> Don't forget to turn off the light before going to bed!

Is it latter correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an interesting question as both are correct terms and can be used at will for most situations.
The first usage is the most common. The second is more formal and is likely to be used as part of a list of instructions.
For example:
List of things to do next week while I'm away:
On Tuesday, take out the rubbish.
On Friday, do the shopping.
Don't forget to turn off the light before going to bed.
Here, the instruction implies that it's meant for every night of the week.
By contrast, the other version might more commonly be used by one person to another (or others) as an instruction for this occassion only, though it could also cover a period of time depending on the context.
 If the usage of the phrases were swapped for these examples it would still be clearly understood but might raise an eyebrow or two.
Equally, "before you go" implies a known subject whereas "before going" is more generic and, therefore, more likely to be found in a written context.

Comment: I'm not saying you're *necessarily* wrong, but I'm deeply suspicious of your assertion that *before you go to bed* is more "common" than *before going to bed*. It's possible that children and non-native speakers might be slightly less likely to use the second (gerund) form, and it's also possible people might be slightly less likely to introduce a pronoun in some formal/official contexts. But in general I would say both forms are used equally.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Anyway, "raise an eyebrow or two" about what exactly?

Comment: I think it's fair to say that people will more often say "before you go to bed" if they are talking about a specific situation, and "before going to bed" if they are conveying a set of general instructions. Having no data on whether people more often give orders for specific situations or for general instructions, I'm also skeptical of the assertion that one occurs more often than the other.

Comment: I agree that there is insufficient data to make any real assertions one way or the other. On that basis my comments, which I still stand by, should be considered as my own personal viewpoint as a 50 year old native English speaker. I believe that, although each phrase is grammatically correct, in certain circles they may be considered either "too posh" or "too familiar", depending on the audience. I take no offence from any remarks and hope none is taken from mine. @FumbleFingers "deeply suspicious"? Of what am I suspected? [raises an eyebrow - sarcasm, in the nicest possible way of course!].

Comment: @user2422586: It's probably not that easy to draw conclusions about relative prevalence. There are about 10 times as many written instances of *before going to bed* in Google Books, compared to *before **you go** to bed*. But comparable contexts for the former would include different [pro]nouns and tenses *(before **John went** to bed)*, and I couldn't begin to guess how much you should factor in because of that. All I know is I'm not aware of any *significant* difference in prevalence. But if you tell a *learner* one occurs "more" than the other, they'll probably just stick to the common one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think we're actually in complete agreement and I certainly agree wholeheartedly with your latest comment - as per my final sentence in my original comment. I'll certainly take on board your final comment for future reference.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the average seven-year-old would be more likely to say *"I always brush my teeth before **I go** to bed"* than *"I always brush my teeth before **going** to bed"*. But that's just because the second form is a bit "advanced" for kids. But adult native speakers are hardly going to be intimidated by gerunds. And I personally don't see any justification for Bob's assertion that the simple form applies more to a single instance, and the gerund form to repeated actions (or indeed that *giving orders* is any different to simple *statements* in terms of the preferred verb form).

Answer (score -1):

If we want to use a verb after a preposition, it must be a gerund. It is impossible to use an infinitive after a preposition.Here are some examples: "I will see him before going to work."" He phoned me after having lunch" So your second sentence is correct.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by *it is impossible to use an infinitive after a preposition* - but I'm pretty sure you're mistaken, and it seems to have nothing to do with the choice between OP's two examples anyway.

Comment: Why don't you give me an example of an infinitive after a prepostion?

Comment: I'm sure I could turn something ***up to satisfy*** the basic condition, but I imagine that's not the construction you had in mind! :)

Comment: Well, are you sure that "up" here is a preposition???

Comment: I'm moving *on* to take a new job. I went *out* to wash the car. I came from *behind* to win the race. I went *in* to eat dinner. I ran him *through* to win the duel. I knocked a bit *off* to make the sale. I've put these *down* to provide examples. Those sure look like prepositions to me.  :)

Comment: Are you really sure that these are examples of prepositions???

Comment: @Vic: I think most people would agree mine and Bob's examples do feature words being used as prepositions. But that's not really the point. So far as I'm concerned, the problem with your answer isn't just that I don't believe the "rule" specified in your second sentence is either true or useful. It's the reference to ***infinitive*** that bothers me, since you seem to be implying OP's *"...before you go to bed"* is an infinitive usage. Which it's obviously not, since the verb is inflected in, for example, *"...before **he goes** to bed"*.

Comment: I never said that the first sentence is wrong,(jeysmith  asked us if the second is correct, and I just pointed out the rule) so no my friend, I didn't imply that "before he goes to bed" is an infinitve usage!! It's a time clause introduced b ythe time conjunction "before". As for "up", "in", "off", etc. they are not always considered prepostions in a sentence. They might function as adverbs. So yes, I do insist that if we need to use a verb form after a preposition, then that would have to be a gerund.